# URL_NOT_RESET error when creating account using POSTMAN

Tags: rest-api

I have used Postman and authenticated with Salesforce Sandbox using Oauth2.

Requested token and added the bearer token to the header without issue.  However when I attempted to submit the below payload with Postman

[image: Postman Authorization screen shot]

[image: Screen shot of Postman Header for account record creation]

```
{
  "Name" : "Test Account creation 1"
}
```

I received the below response:

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "URL_NOT_RESET",
    "message": "Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set"
  }
]
```

Can someone point to me what I have done wrong?

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: when you submit the request. what endpoint you used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you first login with URL `https://login.salesforce.com` your response may look like as below. There is an attribute `instance_url` present in the response along with access token.

Next time for any transaction you have to use this URL. For Example to execute Query your URL will form as  `https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/query?q=Select Name From Account`.

Similarly for update the URL will look like `https://na15.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Z8Tzf?_HttpMethod=PATCH`.

```
{
    "access_token": "00Di0000000inoh!ARUAQIYg09HiVSgeluCud3M.bqL1Ai8l.yEGwE5g8Dh1MTVrbySZ4IHT3jGr2gqq4B1bc4QC.cEqxuvm913LwaT_YsG729",
    "instance_url": "https://na15.salesforce.com",
    "id": "https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Di0000000inohEAA/005i0000002WjJQAA0",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "issued_at": "1466078719920",
    "signature": "fjdMvYTM2K8RzA7SkcXRuy6uyA3eX/BQoQBZuXYgzxQ="
}
```

You have to change the **URL present in your second screenshot** based on the `instance_url` received from login response.

Comment: Thank you so much Saroj.  I am still a noob in using Salesforce API.
So, in summary, use the login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com (sandbox) URL for authentication and obtain the access token but when making the actual API requests (Query or Update), you have to use the instances's URL.